# Automating Excel macro using python

Tags: python, linux, excel, automation

I am using python in Linux to automate an excel. I have finished writing data into excel by using pyexcelerator package.

Now comes the real challenge. I have to add another tab to the existing sheet and that tab should contain the macro run in the first tab. All these things should be automated. I Googled a lot and found win32come to do a job in macro, but that was only for windows.

Anyone have any idea of how to do this, or can you guide me with few suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Excel Macros are per sheets, so, I am afraid, you need to copy the macros explicitly if you created new sheet, instead of copying existing sheet to new one.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that [Resolver One](http://www.resolversystems.com/) is better for what you want - it's a python-scriptable spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe manipulating your .xls with Openoffice and pyUno is a better way. Way more powerful.